# Program (still) does not show up in windows 7 recent programs

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I use Wunderlist (v2) a lot. I would like it to show up in my recent programs list on Windows 7, and I don't want to pin it to the top. But no matter how many times I run it, it does not show up on my recent list.

I have already reset the list multiple times (as prescribed in this post [Program Does Not Show Up in Windows 7 Recent Programs](https://superuser.com/questions/257229/program-does-not-show-up-in-windows-7-recent-programs)).

I notice that when I hover over the shortcut to Wunderlist (in All Programs) it says Type: ClickOnce Application Reference. Does that have anything to do with it?

I found the wunderlist.exe file and ran that, and that didn't work either. Wunderlist did not show up on the start menu.

Comment: I thought about making this an "answer" but I don't think it's actually working correctly. Wunderlist support said a new version might fix it. I installed the latest version on top of my current install. No change in Windows behavior. I then uninstalled Wunderlist and installed it fresh. Now it shows up on the list, but it is highlighted with a peach-colored background as if it were a fresh install. No matter how many times I quit the program and restart it, it doesn't climb the list over programs that were only opened once.

Comment: I just removed the program from the list, closed Wunderlist, and then ran Wunderlist again. The program failed to show back up on the list. I'm back to square one.